# is it possible to log how the jvm was called (including all -D -Xmx etc)

Tags: java, logging, command-line

In order to facilitate troubleshooting, I would like to log to our log files exactly how the java process was invoked.

This should ideally include:

- arguments: ok that is easy, I am already doing that.
- -Xmx256m -XX:+UseParallelGC type stuff
- -Dsome.arg=VALUE stuff
- other params like -server -cp "./lib;./bin" ...

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I **NEED** to do this from inside java, not outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments%28%29):

```
List<String> arguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

This will only return arguments that are passed to the JVM during initialization.

Further information might be found with the other methods of `RuntimeMXBean`, such as [`getClassPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getClassPath%28%29), [`getVmName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getVmName%28%29), ...

Comment: Nice, I tested it and given "-Dnet.val=true -server -Xmx512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -cp "..." returns "-Dnet.val=true -Xmx512m -XX:+UseParallelGC" so -server and -cp are missing. This is already something though...

Comment: see the other methods on that MXBean, `getClasspath()` and `getVmName()`. The latter says something like "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM" for -server or "Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM"

Answer (score 0):

You have a batch file which starts your application and have the echo statements to print the details you listed above.

For example have a ENV VAR as JAVA_OPTS then set the value for it as below

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms128m -Xmx1024m
```

Once it is set use the echo statements like below to print the details.

```
echo   JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
```